# Play Youtube video in a UIWebView without full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I would like to emebed a Youtube video in my app. But normal technique is, we embed a youtube video in a UIWebView and when user clicks, it automatically launches in a MPMoviePlayerController. But this launches in full screen. How to play this youtube video in a MPMoviePlayerController without going to full screen. I would like to display this in a half of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you set **allowsinlinemediaplayback**. but this feature on iPad. in iPhone not applicable. If you try play video with uiwebview on iPhone it will be played in full screen mode.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to do that. In addition to setting:

```js
videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

The easiest and dirtiest way is to disable controls like this:

### Method 1

> Notice `controls: 0`

```js
const player = new YT.Player("player", {
  width: "100%",
  height: "50%",
  videoId: "[your video id]",
  playerVars: {
    controls: 0,
    rel: 0,
    modestbranding: 1,
    html5: 1,
    showinfo: 0,
  },
});
```

### Method 2

> HTML Embedded iFrame code (notice the `&controls=0` and/or `&playsinline=1`)

```html
<iframe
  id="ytplayer"
  type="text/html"
  width="100%"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/[your_video_id]?autoplay=1&controls=0&playsinline=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&html5=1"
  webkit-playsinline
  frameborder="0"
></iframe>;
```

You only add `&playsinline=1` (or `playsinline:1` in the Javascript case next inside the `playerVars`)
In this case, user will still be able to go full screen, but the player should start normally in the borders of your view.

I hope this helps.

Comment: DO you have any working example for this? It will be a great help

Answer (score 6):

I'm using a UIView which is defined as a `YTPlayerView` to play the video.

I followed this tutorial: [YouTube Tutorial to Embed Video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)

I created a dictionary. I then added it to the videoId definition (which video I'm playing).

**From YouTube Tutorial:**

> Replace the `loadWithVideoId`: call with this code:

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
 NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
   @"playsinline" : @YES,
 };

[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE" playerVars:playerVars];
```

**Swift 2.1:**

```
   var playerVars = ["playsinline" : 1]

   videoId.loadWithVideoId(["videoId"], playerVars: playerVars)
```

This will disable the full screen when trying to play the video, and it will also allow the user to go full screen if they want.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Is it against Youtube api ToS?

Comment: No. It's not. Everyone uses it. @RoiMulia

Comment: @Lukesivi Your share link contain code in objective c. Can you please share some same code link for swift

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the video in html5 file and add `webkit-playsinline` in the attribute of `<video>` tag. Then set `webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;` That works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

There still doesn't seem to be a way to do this with `MPMoviePlayerController`, but the best workaround that uses a UIWebView is the `YTPlayer` open sourced by Youtube. You can get the source on [Github](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper), then you can just follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

I simply followed that tutorial and it works pretty well and is fairly customizable. Full screen plays in an `AVFullScreenViewController` which is a system standard, thus, it can be rotated for even better full screen viewing.